# How to customize the summary page to also show specific field values?

Tags: orbeon, populate

The summary page shows default summary information in the table, with the creation and last-modify metadata field. How can I customize this table with some field from the content of the document?

Comment: Hi, What do you mean by summary form?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly from Form Builder: for the control or controls you want to show in the summary page, click on the cogwheel to the right of the control, and in the dialog check the box "Show in Summary".

[image: Control details]

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Orbeon Forms, however I would recommend the documentation as a good starting point.

http://www.orbeon.com/forms/documentation